# Command to generate annotations

Tags: annotations, intellij-idea

I've been looking through the documentation of Intellij 12 but i couldn't find my answer. I'm currently using Intellij 12 with AndroidAnnotations on an Android Project. The project consists of multiple modules, but only 1 uses the Annotations, the rest are libraries an dependencies.

When I rebuild the entire project, the annotations are regenerated. But this takes quite much longer then making my main module and running it. I'm looking for a way to regenerate the annotations on command (by action or ant), so i can include that on my run configuration.

I remember using Intellij 11 and that would regenerate the annotations on every run, but 12 seems to handle things differently.